# Dropbox + personal website

Tags: dropbox

I just found out DropBox(free) and I'm not sure if using it as a private storage for file uploads for a website is allowed and is not considered an abuse of their service.

For example, a blogger displays in image in his/her article and that image is stored in his/her dropbox.

Or a portfolio site of an artist featuring his/her artwork samples in his website and those pictures of his art are stored from his/her dropbox.

And how about a small commercial website like a website of a restaurant featuring its dishes?

Comment: That's the exact duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're asking if you can host a website with Dropbox?

**Yes**. See the unofficial [Dropbox wiki](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/host-websites-with-dropbox).

There are also third-party tools that makes Dropbox website hosting simpler, like [KISSr](https://www.kissr.com/).